# estimate of holder norm of a product

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, holder-spaces

In a book 'Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second Order' by Gilbarg and Trudinger I stumbled upon the following inequality for two functions $f, g$ and their Holder norms in bounded domains $\Omega$ (eq 4.7):

$$[f g]_{\gamma} \leq \max(1, d^{\alpha + \beta - 2\gamma}) [f]_{\alpha} [g]_{\beta} $$

where $\gamma = \min(\alpha, \beta)$ and $d = \text{diam}\ \Omega$, $[f]_{\alpha} = \sup_{x \neq y} \frac{ f(x) - f(y) }{ \lvert x - y \rvert^{\alpha}}$

It's easy to prove that $fg$ is $\gamma$-Holder (we use Holder embedding in compact spaces):

$$[fg]_{\gamma} = \sup_{x \neq y} \frac{ \lvert f(y) g(y) - f(x) g(x) \rvert }{ \lvert x - y \rvert ^{\gamma} }\leq \sup_{x \neq y} \bigg( | f(x) | \frac{ |g(x) - g(y)| }{|x-y|^{\gamma}} + |g(x)|\frac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{|x-y|^{\gamma}} \bigg) \leq |f|_{\infty} [g]_{\gamma} + |g|_{\infty} [f]_{\gamma} $$

so $[fg]_{\gamma}$ is bounded by finite norms of $f,g$.

Then $|f|_{\infty} = \sup_{x \in \Omega} |f(x)| = \sup_{x \in \Omega} | f(x) - f(x_0) + f(x_0) | \leq |f(x_0)| + [f]_{\gamma} |x - x_0|^{\gamma}$

now if $x_0$ is taken such that $f(x_0) = 0$, then we can bound it by:
$$[fg]_{\gamma} \leq 2 [f]_{\gamma} [g]_{\gamma} d^{\gamma}$$

which is far from satisfying - not to mention that such $x_0$ does not necessarily have to exist.

Comment: There has to be an additional assumption on $f$ and $g$, such that vanishing at one point, because if not, taking $f$ constant yields $[g]_γ ≤ 0$, which is for sure false in general.

Comment: good catch, but in the book they use separate notation for functions with compact support, which doesn't appear in this inequality...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I checked the Gilbarg and Trudinger, but the equation (4.7) is actually not for the Hölder seminorms $[f]_\alpha$ but for the **norms**
$$
\|f\|_{C^{\alpha}} = \|f\|_{C^{0,\alpha}} = \|f\|_{L^\infty} + [f]_\alpha.
$$
For these norms, the relation indeed holds since (taking to simplify $\alpha =\beta$)
$$
\begin{align*}
\|fg\|_{C^{0,\alpha}} &= \|fg\|_{L^\infty} + [fg]_\alpha
\\
&≤ \|f\|_{L^\infty}\|g\|_{L^\infty} + \|f\|_{L^\infty}[g]_\alpha + 
[f]_\alpha \|g\|_{L^\infty}
\\
&≤ \|f\|_{C^{0,\alpha}} \, \|g\|_{C^{0,\alpha}}
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: ok, I see it, thank you (if anyone else is confused, take a closer look at eq (4.6) )